# initial and final objects in category of sets

Tags: category-theory

Could someone please tell me what are the initial and final objects
in the category of sets and topological spaces?
I had been very confused by this question.
Thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects

Comment: I should have looked here first! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many concrete categories, the initial object is either the empty object, or some similar thing like the free object on no generators.

In many concrete categories, the terminal object is the one-point set.

Comment: I think it should be "in many $\textit {interesting} $ concrete categories". Otherwise, your claim is just not true.